# How to Pass a value from One Function to Another without Triggering Another Function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, function, avatar

When dealing with React Avatar, whenever I try to upload a picture by cropping it, for each crop the OnCrop function is triggered. However, I need to pass the onCrop value to the Upload() function without invoking Upload() function. The Upload() function needs to be invoked only when the button is clicked. Or any other ideas to improve my code, so that when I hit my Upload button, the final value generated by OnCrop would sent to the server. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
const App = () =>{

function Oncrop(pv){
   const file = pv;
   Upload(file);

}

function Upload(file){
   axios.post("/api",file);
}


return(
<Avatar     width={200}
            height={200}
            onCrop={onCrop}
            onClose={onClose}
            src={null}
/>   
<button onClick={Upload}>Upload</button>  

)

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a state to do it:

```
const [file, setFile] = useState();
function Oncrop(pv){
   setFile(pv)
}
function Upload(){
   axios.post("/api",file);
}
```